# Select Max value seems not to work to avoid duplicates

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql statement like this:

```
Select myId, valueChar, initialDate from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
inner join t3 on t1.id=t3.id and deleted<>1
inner join t4 on t4.id=t3.id
inner join t5 on t4.id=t2.id and module='XXX'
inner join t6 on t6.id=t5.id
inner join t7 on t7.id=t6.id and valueChar like 'AB%'
```

This returns

<kbd>myId</kbd><kbd>charValue</kbd><kbd>initialDate</kbd>
<kbd>XX7334HD</kbd><kbd>ABY</kbd><kbd>2015-09-01</kbd>
<kbd>ZY8754UD</kbd><kbd>ABZ</kbd><kbd>2015-11-21</kbd>
<kbd>BB7777AA</kbd><kbd>ABD</kbd><kbd>2016-07-11</kbd>
<kbd>BB7777AA</kbd><kbd>ABE</kbd><kbd>2016-12-01</kbd>

As you can see all the rows are different in ID, but there is one id duplicated (it is possible) with different char value. I need that this duplicate dissapears taking always in these cases the max initialDate.

This should return

<kbd>myId</kbd><kbd>charValue</kbd><kbd>initialDate</kbd>
<kbd>XX7334HD</kbd><kbd>ABY</kbd><kbd>2015-09-01</kbd>
<kbd>ZY8754UD</kbd><kbd>ABZ</kbd><kbd>2015-11-21</kbd>
<kbd>BB7777AA</kbd><kbd>ABE</kbd><kbd>2016-12-01</kbd>

To do this I tried with `max(initialDate)` on the above statement but seems that does not work because it mix both registers, returns the correct id, the correct initialDate but with the charValue of the other row...

What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
and t4.id=(
        select max(t42.id)
        from t4 t42
        inner join t3 t32 on t42.id = t32.id
        inner join t2 t22 on t22.id=t32.id
        )
```

but now it only return one valuew...

Answer (score 0):

When using a MAX() function you also need to use GROUP BY. Problem would be the valueChar or charValue column. That will result in a random value. Because you only tell mysql to get the max for initialDate.

So you need to figure out the id for the max(initialDate). I cannot write the exact query, because I do not know in which table the initialDate is stored.

And you're query is extremly strange. You join t4 and in the corresponding on-part there is no reference to t4. Please re-check your on-parts.

Comment: I have fixed the error on t4, it was a typo. If I use group by myId it does not work, returns exactly the same...

The initialDate is on t6. What do you mean with I have to figure out the id for the max initial date?

Comment: I edited the question with what I understend that I should do, but does not work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to also do a `group by` along with `max()` like

```
Select myId, valueChar, max(initialDate) from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
inner join t3 on t1.id=t3.id and t3.deleted<>1
inner join t4 on t1.id=t3.id
inner join t5 on t4.id=t2.id and t5.module='XXX'
inner join t6 on t6.id=t5.id
inner join t7 on t7.id=t6.id and t7.valueChar like 'AB%'
group by myId;
```

Note: If `Full Group By` mode is on then the suggested query won't work

Comment: Be careful, it is unclear which valueChar you will get. It might not be the right one.